# How to set application path?

Tags: c++, qt, path

I wrote console Qt application. I'd like to copy file from directory, where is my exe file.

```
m_Path = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "\\g.aux.xml";
QFile::copy(m_Path,PathNew);
```

This code excellent works, when I debug my application. But when I copy my .exe file to another directory it does not work.

Please tell me, how fix it.

UPD:
I think I found the answer
I need to use QDir::currentPath()

[Get current working directory in a Qt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402576/how-to-get-current-working-directory-in-a-qt-application)

Comment: What does "does not work" mean. How does it fail. Please describe the problem completely. Please describe the precise layout of files.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely missing .dll files.

Copying only the .exe file is not enough for Qt applications - you must make sure the necessary dynamic libraries are in the same directory as the .exe. In your case, copying `QtCore4.dll` or `Qt5Core.dll` from your compiler's directory should do, but you'll want to read [this page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment.html) for more details in the future.

Also, in the future, please describe your problem with more detail.

Comment: I deploy this application (it works). This application creates world files. But it does not copy files.

The question is "How to set application path?"

Comment: In the past files was situated on the disk C. The directory was C:\bin\...  And I always copy this files before working. Now I do not want to copy this files yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was a deployment issue. In this case, you'll probably want to check if `applicationDirPath()` returns the correct directory, and if `PathNew` points where it's supposed to. You might have to convert backslashes to forward slashes, or the other way around. That's all I know.