# Accessing PWD in C++ Code

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

In Qt Creator in the Projects Build Settings, you can set environment variables so that once you're done your system does not retain the env vars that were set while developing.  The environment variable I have would contain the path of the developer's code.  I would like to not have each developer have to input this value.  I have read that there's a .pro.shared that can contain this information, however since the environment variable will point to the user's code directory and will be different for each user, it would not work for this.

What is the best way to do this?

I tried variations of the following:

MyProject.pro

```
DEFINES += MY_VAR=$PWD
```

main.cpp

```
#ifdef MY_VAR
qDebug() << "printing value: " << QString(MY_VAR);
#endif
```

Any suggestions are welcomed.  The solution I'm looking for doesn't have to be a .pro file edit, as long as it is something that can be version controlled.

Not a duplicate question because...There are folders in my app's code that are relative to the application's directory. Because the end user's application and a developer's application will be in different places, I want to allow the developer to use directories that are relative to where their code resides. So I want to set the variable at build time and use it at run time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current working directory in a Qt application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402576/get-current-working-directory-in-a-qt-application)

Comment: So you want current directory at build time? Or runtime?

Comment: There are folders in my app's code that are relative to the application's directory.  Because the end user's application and a developer's application will be in different places, I want to allow the developer to use directories that are relative to where their code resides.  So I want to set the variable at build time and use it at run time.

Comment: @kmx78 Paths set at build time sound like a bad time.

Comment: I'm not trying to set a path, just trying to have access to a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just happened to have stumbled across the solution somewhere else.  In case anyone else is still looking, it turns out that all I needed were 3 back slashes for quotes in my .pro file:

```
DEFINES += MY_VAR=\\\"$$PWD\\\"
```